# gksudo asks for password every time

Tags: debian, sudo, password

This is using Ubilinux based on Debian stretch but the same behavior happens with Ubuntu 16.04 and probably others.

gksudo asks for my password every single time.. I can easily enough configure regular sudo to asks password only every three hours by using visudo. But this does not "take" on gksudo.

Is there any way to make gksudo "remember" the password for some time?

Comment: `ssh-agent`  probably is not running. Is it installed?

Comment: gksudo should never ask for the root password.  It should ask for _your_ password.  Unless you're logged in as root, in which case: why are you logging into a GUI as root?

Comment: Okay, I corrected the question to say it asks for *my* password. @RuiFRibeiro why would ssh keychain agent affect gksudo? I enabled it anyways and it did nothing as expected. I don't have any ssh keys installed to start with.

Comment: Bah humbug. Looks like there's no way around this annoyance. Perhaps another program than gksudo. Plain old sudo fails in XRDP session due to not connecting to the screen unless you remove the access control with xhost +

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured globally for all sudo-like programs with the `timestamp_type` variable in `sodoers(5)`.

The following (executed as root) creates an appropriate file that sets this variable so that all invocations of respective users are cached no matter how they have been executed. Beware any security squirrels biting your head off though!

```
echo 'Defaults  timestamp_type=global' >/etc/sudoers.d/timestamp_type
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/timestamp_type
chown 0:0 /etc/sudoers.d/timestamp_type
```